# hardhat script giving this error when ran

Tags: dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, flash-loans, flashbots, arbitrage

Please, I need help clearing this.

```
root@DESKTOP-O7HMHFH:/mnt/c/pr0/projects/arbitrage/comp# npx hardhat run scripts/manipulate.js --network localhost

Beginning Swap...

Input Token: COMP
Output Token: WETH

ProviderError: HttpProviderError
    at HttpProvider.request (/mnt/c/pr0/projects/arbitrage/comp/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:78:19)
    at AutomaticSenderProvider.request (/mnt/c/pr0/projects/arbitrage/comp/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/accounts.ts:341:34)
    at AutomaticGasProvider.request (/mnt/c/pr0/projects/arbitrage/comp/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/gas-providers.ts:135:34)
    at AutomaticGasPriceProvider.request (/mnt/c/pr0/projects/arbitrage/comp/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/gas-providers.ts:182:36)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/mnt/c/pr0/projects/arbitrage/comp/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

I changed the gas limit and tried reducing the amount to manipulate but couldnt get a decent result?

Comment: it would be helpful if you give more context like including code f.e. the `manipulate.js` in your question

Comment: done i was calling the wrong address, thank you

Comment: Just having this issue for now on gas limit